# Changing info issue using git commands

Tags: git

I found this link to understand how to rename author name and email https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/

But it worked for me just for the first time. Now I get this error in terminal:

```
Cannot create a new backup.
A previous backup already exists in refs/original/
Force overwriting the backup with -f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `-f` flag for the `git filter-branch` command.
For example, change the first line of the script from this:

> ```
> git filter-branch --env-filter '
> ```

to this:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter '
```